# Loopback Latency of an Audio CODEC?

Tags: audio, adc, dac, latency, audio-codec

I'm thinking way ahead about a possible future project which will contain, among many other things, a "DIY hearing aid" of sorts.  Microphones feeding earbuds with some DSP in between, all in a physically small space.  Not because I'm hard of hearing, but to account for an acoustic lowpass caused by a different part of the project.

I have some experience using digital live audio systems that claim about 1ms latency from the ADC's, all the way through the (quite involved) DSP, to the DAC's.  In other words, a stereo recorder hooked up to a Y-splitter at the ADC input for one recording channel, and the DAC output for the other recording channel, would measure about 1ms offset between them.  (see the test circuit below)

That's fine for a concert, where you can easily have more physical offset than that (~1 foot) between the mics and speakers, but for my project, I'm looking at several inches at most.

So, to get a feel for what I'm stuck with, and how much I need to optimize and overpower my DSP code to fit in the time remaining <sub>(small buffers, even down to a single sample just to get it out NOW!, which means I can't use SIMD instructions - increased sample rate, not for "audiophool" quality but just to shorten the turn-around time - etc.)</sub>, what latency can I expect for a typical audio CODEC chip in this test circuit?:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fnAh6n.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I expect a minimum of 2 samples, just because of how I2S works - latch and shift out from the ADC, then shift into the DAC and latch again - but I imagine that the conversions themselves aren't instantaneous either.

I've looked at a few datasheets and, at least for the cheap ones, I can't find a parameter that tells me the overall latency.  For their intended application of PC audio, I can understand that it's not important, but for this project, it kinda is.

What parameter(s) should I be looking for in a good datasheet?  And are there any rules of thumb / tribal knowledge that would be useful as well, in terms of realtime DSP where the output might combine with the original input, after a small speed-of-the-wave delay of the original input?  (1's of samples at 48kHz)

---

Of course, all of this might not even matter, depending on the acoustic lowpass that I end up with, for which this DSP needs to be a complimentary highpass with transducer-correction and peak-limiting.  I have no idea what that acoustic lowpass is going to be, so I'm looking for enough general information that I can evaluate it when the time comes.

<sup>(If the crossover frequency ends up being low enough and steep enough (overall latency is a small fraction of a single wave), this may all be a moot point; I'm not going to hear the original anyway, where it matters, so just throw some pre-fab code at it and call it good.  Or the crossover might be high or gradual enough that it does matter...)</sup>

Anyway, I'm looking for enough general information that I can evaluate it when the time comes.  Thanks!

Comment: Why not go pure analog to measure phase shift with distance and use a graphic equalizer to wired ear buds. Then latency is only limited by your electronics ( near 0) and 10 to 90% Risetime = 35% of BW 1/f. What is the end result?

Comment: An equalized spectrum of what medium?  Graphic equalizers can be made pretty tiny.

Comment: If you can’t make it work with pure analog, it will be even harder with a  DSP.

Comment: The digital filter in the DAC/ADC adds substantial latency also. Might be better off with a SAR ADC, or using the bitstream from the sigma delta directly.

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75  Yes, it would be possible in pure-analog, and that was my original idea, but I won't be able to access it physically while it's running, so some kind of remote adjustment is also required.  (get it close in theory, then final-tweak it "live")  That's plumb easy to add to a digital design, but represents a pretty big increase in complexity and greatly limited options in analog, as not all topologies are easy or even possible to adjust electrically.  (DAC-fed-VCA's and digipots only do so much)

Comment: Then you find that you didn't think of all the options that you really need, and you have to make a whole 'nother board to get them, instead of just reprogramming a chip.  The administration side of things would be SO much easier if it were all digital, so I'm trying to find a way to make the side-effects acceptable, long before I commit to anything and build the rest of the design on it.

Comment: If the answer is that the conversion is inherently too long to make this work, even without *any* DSP code (per my test circuit above), then that's fine, but I'd like for someone to show that if it's true.

Comment: I wish I could see your application and spec  that you have in mind and why latency is important for a few inch phase in dual mic’s. is that to simulate the gap between ears for special acuity?

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75  It's a fairly involved theatrical costume that covers the actor's head, hence the acoustic lowpass.  I just want to replace what is lost, without a comb filter.  Why that's necessary to measure the round-trip delay of an ADC/DAC pair, I don't know.  Like I said, I'm looking for enough information to evaluate it on my own, when the time comes, which it definitely hasn't yet.  Waaaay too may unknowns at this point for anyone to give a solid yes or no answer, so I'm looking for more of a general feel of what the tools themselves do.  Not whether they're a good fit or not.

Comment: In-ear monitoring is also an option, but I would LOVE it if I could do both: use the IEM on stage, and the self-contained amplification to interact with the audience in the lobby or on the street, etc.  I'm not concerned about the IEM's latency, since it's a different signal from what's in the air.  The local mic and processing form a parallel path with the direct sound, and that *does* care about a difference in latency, or it creates a comb filter.

Answer (score 1):

Didn't you just specify the answer?

You said spacing of "a couple inches".  Sound is roughly 1ms per foot.  Let's assume 4 inches which means *roughly* 400us (I'm being *VERY* loose to make the math easy).

At 48KHz, samples are roughly every 20us--so you get 20 samples (400us/20us) to stay within your latency budget.

If you run that up to 192KHz, you get 80 samples.

The codecs are probably close to 1 sample of latency on DAC and ADC if you turn off on-board DSP processing.  Nobody actually tries to delay things (unless you have on-board processing and ask them to), but you have to have a full sample in order to transmit/receive on the digital bus.

As for vector instructions, even if you only had 1 current time sample to work with, you've got lots of DSP algorithms which work with quite a few past time samples so SIMD vector instructions would still be a win.

I would also caution you about being too stringent in your audio specifications.  Most people have ... quite imperfect hearing.  I have created audio systems where there was a variable 5-8% pitch shift (for delay compensation reasons in really bad cases).  It was *painful* for me to hear, but the vast majority of people didn't even notice even after I pointed it out.

I recommend that you set your specifications to the *human perception average* and allow tweaks for those who are outside the norm.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hmm...your anecdote about most people not hearing a problem that is obvious to you, even after you pointed it out, is encouraging...except that I'm one of those who tends to notice that sort of thing.  :-/  Looking at failure modes also seems a bit encouraging even then: if my system *is* inadequate, it'll be a comb filter, and our ears seem to be pretty good at ignoring those since they occur all the time in nature anyway.  So maybe it *can* work to just let it do what it's going to, with a known-good codebase.

Comment: I know that no one *intentionally* delays these things, but I also know that there's inherently some required just because of how the process works.  So I'm asking about that, more than anything else.  In the test circuit shown in the question, how long does it take for an impulse, step-change, or other recognizable feature to make it all the way through?  Not just the mechanics of serial communication, but coming up with a digital representation in the first place, and then using it at the end.  A SAR ADC, for example, isn't instantaneous, but audio is probably delta-sigma...

Comment: You are arguing with the datasheet about "sample rate".  The datasheet says a sample drops every 20ms at 48KHz, so that's what happens.  These aren't mega-speed RF ADCs that deep pipeline because the analog sample rate and digital data rate are similar.  Nobody keeps a pipeline of analog samples around at audio speeds--that would be a waste of silicon.  The delta-sigma converters are internally being clocked at many MHz (20MHz+), not KHz, and work one audio sample at a time. Audio is *sloooooow* relative to the digital blocks.  Consequently, the delta-sigma *audio clock* latency is 1.

Comment: "*Nobody keeps a pipeline of analog samples around at audio speeds--that would be a waste of silicon.*"  Not intentionally, no.  I never claimed that anyone did.  "*...and work one audio sample at a time.*"  I knew they were super-fast, low-resolution converters that were "noised up" on purpose (all high-frequencies) and then lowpassed to both fill in the lesser bits and remove that noise before taking every 1000th sample or whatever and throwing away the rest, but considering that 1) that's some DSP work *in the converter itself*, and 2) DSP usually implies non-zero latency......

Comment: Anyway, you're saying that my test circuit will give an offset of two I2S sample periods between channels of the stereo analog recorder, regardless of the sample clock rate?  That implies that they use IIR filters internally, as FIR's tend to misbehave in other ways if you optimize them for super-low latency.  That seems plausible to me, even if FIR's otherwise lend themselves perfectly to sample-rate conversion in one step, as a lowpass that only calculates the *required* output samples and not everything.  If I interpreted you correctly, then this sounds like the first real answer.

Comment: I expect so, yes.  However, I would recommend that you go dig at delta-sigma converters.  You have some misconceptions about them that you probably want to correct before throwing DSP algorithms on top of their outputs/inputs.  Delta-sigma converters do *not* throw samples away--they oversample it quite a lot and their comparators are *very* high resolution.  Delta-sigma does not add noise inherently, but it does *shape* the base noise.  Finally, adding noise (called dithering) in fact *increases* the overall noise floor even at low frequencies, but breaks up sampling artifacts.  Good luck.

Comment: Maybe we have a difference in understanding the terms then.  (+1 for that comment)  "Oversampling" to me, necessarily requires throwing some away (decimating) later, and that's fine if the signal contains nothing higher than the resulting Nyquist cutoff.  If you're going to lowpass digitally, then the minimum sample rate of the input is higher than the minimum sample rate of the output.  This decimation might not necessarily be an explicit step, just a side-effect of something else.  For example...

Comment: ...one of my previous projects had a 10-bit SAR ADC running as fast as it could (~100ksps), measuring a manual operator's control with lots of uncorrelated electronic noise, and the ADC interrupt routine did a 1st-order IIR lowpass on it (also called an "exponential average") with a ~10Hz cutoff (calculated from the sample rate, of course - DSP only understands samples, not time) before writing it to a 16-bit global variable, which a PID loop would take as its setpoint whenever it got around to it.  Lots of ADC samples per PID scan.

Comment: All the principles that I described are there: oversampling with noise, lowpassing to convert that noise to better resolution, and then using the result at a lower sample rate.  The explanations that I've seen of delta-sigma are pretty much that, except that most of them use a 1 bit converter (analog comparator or using the digital bit directly - a "1-bit DAC" is just a wire) with maybe an 8-bit digital interface.  Real-world designs probably use a few more bits, like maybe 8 or so as a flash ADC or an R-2R DAC as those are practically instantaneous, but my understanding is pretty much that.

Answer (score 0):

### What parameter(s) should I be looking for in a good datasheet?

I think I finally stumbled onto the answer for this one.  It's called "Group Delay", as on pages 16 and 20 of [this datasheet](https://statics.cirrus.com/pubs/proDatasheet/CS42436_F4.pdf).  It appears to be measured in samples, though the datasheet gives the unit in seconds and the number as x/Fs.
Page 21 gives the valid sample rates for each mode.

I had to google "group delay", because it wasn't something I was familiar with, and found [this useful explanation](https://circuitcellar.com/research-design-hub/group-delay-basics-more-filter-fun/).  So in the context of an ADC or DAC filter, it seems that the converter itself does indeed delay the signal by that many samples.

In the case of the one linked here, that's 12 or 9 samples for the ADC at 48kHz or 96kHz, respectively, and 10 or 5 samples for DAC, for a total round-trip of 22 or 14 samples from analog in to analog out, just in the converter chip itself.

Converting to time and then distance in air gives ~460us|~6in|~15cm or ~150us|~2in|~5cm.

I think I can work with the shorter of those, provided I can keep up with twice the number of samples!  Even if it does comb-filter at the very top end (the wavelength of 20kHz in air is ~5/8in|~1.5cm), it's pretty well attenuated acoustically (the reason this project exists in the first place) so it's probably not noticeable.  As long as it lines up closely enough through the crossover region (acoustic lowpass, DSP highpass), I'll be happy.

Interestingly enough, the delay figure for 48kHz is almost half of the 1ms that the commercial live sound gear advertises for its total latency.  I guess it would be reasonable for some complex routing and a handful of transports to take the other 26 samples or so.

### And are there any rules of thumb / tribal knowledge that would be useful as well, to avoid an acoustic comb filter from a live / realtime DSP...?

Well, an obvious one, given the first part of this answer, is to run the system as fast as you have enough clocks per sample for in the DSP!  What that number is, depends on what your DSP is, what the processing is, and how you optimize that processing.

96kHz isn't going to sound any different from 48kHz, but with the codec mentioned above, it results in ~1/3 the latency!